# KDE config file for window settings, sizes, etc.?

Tags: configuration, kde, window, display-settings, settings

What config file stores the settings for KDE window settings, sizes, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some common ones for KDE4 are in `~/.kde4/share/config/kwinrc`. But some configs are app-controlled. Many apps have their config files in the same dir.